# How to create a directory in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a folder in the storage folder in Laravel, but I keep getting this error:

```
mkdir(): No such file or directory
```

I get what that means, but I thought it would be possible to create one with either:

```
File::makeDirectory(storage_path("story/$story->id"));
```

or

```
mkdir(storage_path("story/$story->id"));
```

but both of them are giving me the error above.

Comment: try `File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);`

Comment: Try to set write permission to storage and see ? chmod -R 775 storage or chmod -R 777 storage

Comment: does `story` exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a defined permission:

```
File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory', 0775);
```

Also, refer to:
"[How to create directory if not exists in Laravel 7.x and 6.x?](https://hdtuto.com/article/how-to-create-directory-if-not-exists-in-laravel-6)".

Answer (score 0):

This is from an existing project:

```
if($request->hasFile('cover_image'))
    {
        // Get the file with extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
        //Get the file name
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        //Get the ext
        $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //File name to store
        $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        //Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAS('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
    }
```

This creates a folder in public folder and save the file. Rest you can use it anywhere with variable $fileNameToStore